# Обозначение указателей в C++

Tags: c++, c, указатели

Здравствуйте.
Есть ли какие-нибудь существенные различия между такими определениями указателя:

```
int* a;

int *b;
```

Также хотелось бы выяснить, выигрывает ли в быстродействии определение типа "указатель на указатель". Стоит ли его использовать, или это является плохим стилем? Какую альтернативу можно применить, если лучше стараться избегать такого:

```
int var = 123; 
int *ptrvar = &var;
int **ptr_ptrvar = &ptrvar; 
int ***ptr_ptr_ptrvar = &ptr_ptrvar;
```

Answer (score 15):

- В первом случае с точки зрения поведения разницы нет. Где ставить `'*'` в этом случае - это сугубо вопрос вкуса и используемого `coding standard`.
- Говорить о быстродействии в таких вопросах обычно не имеет смысла, поскольку шанс того, что передача объекта по указателю станет узким местом вашего приложения, очень близок к нулю даже под платформами типа `ARM`.

> *Если, конечно, хочется пообсуждать, то делать это нужно, имея `N` ассемблерных листингов `gcc, cl, clang и icc` с разными уровнями оптимизаций, хотя у меня есть сильное подозрение, что он будет одинаков для большинства случаев.*

- Поскольку использование многоуровневой адресации (`int ***ptr_ptr_ptrvar`) очень сильно вредит читаемости кода, делать это следует только в случаях, когда без этого действительно не обойтись *(в 99% случаев это - [`bad code smell`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)).*

> Если вам нужно, чтобы значение переменной `var` изменялось в функции, передавайте ее по указателю `[C99]` или иногда, если удобнее, то по ссылке [`C++03`]. Некоторые стандарты явно запрещают передачу переменной с семантикой `out` по неконстантной ссылке [и требуют для этого использования указателя.](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Reference_Arguments)

Comment: Лучшый ответ.

Answer (score 6):

Существенных отличий нет, скорее дело вкуса. Однако следует обратить внимание на следующий момент - несмотря на то, что указатель относится к типу (т.е. тип переменной : указатель на int, или указатель на char), запись вида :

> int *a, b, c;

вовсе не будет означать, что у Вас описаны 3 указателя на int, - это 1 указатель и 2 переменных типа int.
Использование многоуровневой адресации возможно, однако уровни глубже второго (указатель на указатель) применяются крайне редко, да и IMXO, запутывают программу.

Comment: Нужно было делать такой пример:
Запись вида:

    char* a, b, c; // a - указатель, остальное — переменные.
    char *a, *b, *c; // <- все указатели
    const char* const a; // равносильно const char const *a;

По этому, предпочтительней запись вида:

    void *p_foo;

Answer (score 5):

1. Тип переменных

   ```
   int* a;
   int *b;
   int * c;
   int      *                   qewetrye;
   ```

   не различается - это всё указатели на целое.
2. Одинарные, двойные, тройные и т.д. указатели физически ничем не отличаются - это просто адреса в памяти. Использовать указатели вообще и тем более двойные-тройные нужно только там где они действительно нужны.

Comment: Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сказал, что семантически правильной является запись:

```
int *a;
```

а не:

```
int* a;
```

Хотя вроде смысл обоих записей один и тот же, а именно `а` указатель на целое, но попытка написания:

```
int* a, b, c;
```

Не означает, что все три a, b и с являются указателями на целое. Семантически именно это и написано! Типа `int*` - нет! А запись:

```
int *a, b, c;
```

Не вызывает никакой иллюзии. Здесь четко и явно видно что указателем является только а.

Answer (score 2):

Так

```
int*a;
```

и так

```
int   *    b;
```

тоже годится. Количество пробелов влияет только на размер исходного файла.

Указатель на указатель обычно используют для передаче данных в функцию с целью изменения функцией самого указателя.

[@Asen](/users/5040/asen), искусственное "накручивание" адресов применять не надо.

По поводу быстородействия - точно не ускорит.

Answer (score 1):

1. Записи `int* a;` и `int *b;` эквивалентны.
2. Разница появляется в том, что когда нужно в одну строчку объявить несколько указателей. Например:

   `int* a, b, c; // a - указатель, b и с - просто целочисленные переменные
   int* d,*e,*f; // здесь определено три указателя: d, e, f`
3. В случае с применением конструкция `typedef` и `#define` получается интереснее.

   `#define P_INT int*
   typedef int* PINT;
   P_INT d, e, f; // указатель ТОЛЬКО d.
   PINT  a, b, c;  // все три являются указателями`

   Внимание, тут явная ошибка, которую стоит обходить :-) И это еще один повод не пользоваться `define`.
4. Указатель на указатель - это хорошо. По сути мы экономим память (указатель занимает мало места), вместо того, чтобы хранить сами копии объектов целиком, но ценой дополнительного времени на разыменование указателя. С точки зрения использования - вижу смысл использовать такую конструкцию для организации многомерных указателей или изменения значения указателя в ф-циях. А вот разумное применение для указателей на указатели на указатели уже сложно придумать.

Answer (score 0):

```
int              var  = 123;     
auto          ptrvar  = &var;    
auto      ptr_ptrvar  = &ptrvar;     
auto   ptr_ptr_ptrvar = &ptr_ptrvar; 
cout<< " var= " << ***ptr_ptr_ptrvar <<"\n";

//  обычно разыменовывание указателя очень быстрая операция. но нужно смотреть на компилер   
// если хочется передавать данные через * то лучше так:

 vector (const vector &);  // Конструктор копирования (медленный)  
 vector (vector &&);       // Конструктор переноса из временного объекта (быстрый)
```

Comment: @Alex Dok, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.