# Чем отличаются указатели в си

Tags: c++, c

Чем отличается

```
int *sp;
```

от

```
int* sp;
```

Comment: В данном конкретном примере — ничем

Comment: А вообще дубликат вопроса: [Обозначение указателей в C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/114534/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: Второй копировать мышкой легче. А вообще пусть форматтер сам как надо сделает.